# PHP: get php code from DB and run inside a php file only on condition

Tags: php, mysql

I have a php file which queries and runs function ('somefunction') on the element fetched from each row.

The issue is now I have a new column which specifies a condition on sql and based on that condition we have to decide whether to run this function or not.

condition has a php code and it has to be executed, sample is given below

```
<?php   

     $sqlString = 'select * from s_tables';
        $result = mysql_query($sqlString);
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
             $functionName = $row["functionName"];//pre-defined functions inside my php file
             $conditionToCheck = $row["conditionToCheck"];//newly added one, will return a piece of php code
             $stylesToAffect = $row["elementToAffect"];//say html elements H1,H2,P
             if ($conditionToCheck){
                //need to evaluate code which i got from query
                $checkStatus = eval($conditionToCheck);//this is not working
             }

             if ($checkStatus){
                  //this function runs perfectly 
                  if (method_exists($this, $functionName)){
                       $this->$functionName($stylesToAffect);
                  }
             }
        }


        //just for a sample 'conditionToCheck' look like
        $var1 = 2;
        $var2 = 3;
        if ($var1 > $var2){
            $checkStatus = true;
        }else{
            $checkStatus = false;
        }

?>
```

Can any one look into this, Thanks in prior

Comment: what does the function ``eval($conditionToCheck);`` do? Can you post the code?

Comment: eval does nothing, its a php in-built function

Comment: Could you please post sample values of `$conditionToCheck`?

Comment: sample values of $conditionToCheck is given at the bottom of the code itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using same sample code as you mentioned than you just need to return $checkstatus value.

```
$var1 = 2;
$var2 = 3;
if ($var1 > $var2){
    $checkStatus = true;
} else {
    $checkStatus = false;
}
return $checkStatus;
```

Comment: Yeah this has solved my condition, thanks alot.
But if have to perform some scripts on that, is there a way to do it or should i do have a pre-defined function

Answer (score 0):

You cannot not execute php code which is stored in database directly. If you wish to do so then you can use `eval()`.

But you might not want to use this if you consider the potential security threats to such implementations.

I would suggest you not to use `eval()` as if you become a prey to sql injections then this can harm you more.

**Update (after reading comments):**

In your case you might want to use `call_user_func()` so your example would be like `call_user_func($funtionName, $paramsIfAny);` and `eval($conditionsToCheck)`

Also check your condition code you are not returning/echoing anything so your code would be like (as mentioned by @ravindra-bhalothia):

```
$var1 = 2;
$var2 = 3;
if ($var1 > $var2){
    $checkStatus = true;
} else {
    $checkStatus = false;
}
return $checkStatus;
```

Comment: Having a pre-defined function and sending params are OK, but is this the only way, because my conditions aren't of same type

Comment: for that purpose only I have mentioned eval too.

Answer (score 0):

Can you put the condition ??

usually

if

```
$str =  '<?php echo "test"; ?>';

echo eval('?>'.$str);
```

will print "test", thus evaluating the expression. Check if this works for you, otherwise put the condition you are evaluating.

Comment: I dont want it to print, the condition performs a if statement and returns true/false.
ConditionTocheck is given at the bottom of my question

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
$var1 = 1;
$var2 = 3;
$conditionCheck = '$var1 > $var2';
$checkStatus = eval( "return $conditionCheck;");
if ($checkStatus) {
    echo "greater";
} else {
    echo "less";
}
```